# Magento 2: What is the purpose of "_replica" tables?

Tags: database, magento2.4.1

I'm newbie in Magento but I have a store that started in 2.2 and is now updated to 2.4.1.

What is the exact purpose or `_replica` tables? The only mentioning is that they help prevent deadlock but how exactly this process work? Most of my `_replica` tables are empty when indexing is not running but it seems that Magento only grows `catalogrule_product_price_replica` table.
I have 1 million simple products and a handful of price groups and the `catalogrule_product_price_replica` table has data from every day starting in mid November and this table now grew to more than 450 million rows.

Could some point me to a nice description of `_cl`, `_replica` and `_temp########` tables and when they are created by cron and which can be manually truncated when cron dies?

Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: The problem with `catalogrule_product_price_replica` being very large sounds like what's described here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31752

Comment: Yup, that was my bug report and workaround. I was hoping this would get some traction here but after a few days I looked into it and posted the report as it's significant if you have a store with 100k+ items. Hope the answer was useful for some folks as the triggers on _replica tables are not so straightforward.

Answer (score 8):

Answering my own question...

`_cl` tables are for changeLog, i.e., to keep track of which records were changed and need to be reindexed (the number of rows directly corresponds to the number of items in backlog for indexing)

`_temp#####` are temporary tables used for indexing. The parent tables will be removed and `_temp###` tables will be renamed.

`_replica`, as the name suggests, is just a copy of its parent table. The reason behind using `_replica` tables is that they have triggers. If any data is changed in them a record will be created in appropriate `_cl` table. One can remove `_replica` tables but no changes will be indexed until full re-index is run but you **can change a lot of data without hogging your database with triggers**.

Answer (score 5):

I'll just expand a bit Andrew's own answer with additional info that could be useful to those like myself who ended up here searching for an answer why my `catalogrule_product_price_replica` is so large and doesn't get cleaned up.

The `catalogrule_product_price_replica` table shouldn't be larger than `catalogrule_product_price` table - rather it should be basically the same size.
If your replica table is growing (rapidly daily) then you are probably using a Magento version (started somewhere around 2.3.5 until 2.4.3) which has an issue with partial reindexing of catalog rules.

This issue was fixed in 2.4.4 and the fixes can be seen here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6e6fff2a87221cd71f0f9e347a1cf35b3460d13f

Just be careful implementing the changes, the target version is 2.4.4 so the fixes in those commits could possibly cause other issues in previous Magento versions.

**EDIT**

I implemented the fix from github on a 2.3.7 live instance and haven't noticed any issues.
The fix basically stops the usage of the `catalogrule_product_price_replica` table as far as I can tell.
So it can be safely truncated and won't get filled anymore.

Comment: My issue report on GitHub that @fredden pointed out has also a workaround for this. I had a nightly job which would clear the table and do a full reindexing which is quick if you enable multithreaded support for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who face this issue:

```
partialUpdateCatalogRuleProductPrice()
```

does not clean expired date rows.

Here is a plugin that does it:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\PartialIndex;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class DeleteOldDate
{
    private $_logger;
     
    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    }
    
    public function afterPartialUpdateCatalogRuleProductPrice(
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\PartialIndex $subject,
        $result
    ): void
    {
        $indexTableName = $this->resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product_price');
        $select = $this->connection->select()->from(
            ['crp' => $indexTableName],
            'rule_date'
        )->group('rule_date');
        $where = ['rule_date' .' NOT IN (?)' => $select];
        //remove expired rule_date
        $this->connection->delete($this->resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product_price_replica'), $where);
    }
}
```

Tested on 2.3.7

Hope this can help.