# Does Magento regenerate the table catalogrule_product_price_replica if I remove it?

Tags: magento2, bug

I am in a situation where table `catalogrule_product_price_replica` has grown too big (about 500M rows, due to the bug in some versions on Magento). Trying to delete redundant lines (1000 at times, my script has deleted about 10M rows during the last 8 hours) is like carving a rock with a toothpick.

If I understand correctly, tables with `_replica` postfix have some secondary utility function and if I am correct they don't seem to be a part of Magento DB dumps.

As this table has grown so big (filled the whole filesystem to the critical point), the easiest way is to drop the table and create or let Magento automatically create the table again. As I am not too familiar with Magento's inner life, I am not eager to drop tables on the live server...

What problems I will have when I just drop the table? Do I need to create it again or does it happen automatically? What active data should be in there?

Magento version is 2.4.2, and the [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31752) I was referring to. I am on the edge of migrating to Magento 2.4.6 which does resolve the bug, but we need this system to be online in about a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Magento 2.4.4. The solution involves the removal of the `catalogrule_product_price_replica` table. From the GitHub issue, you can find the related commit on https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amagento%2Fmagento2+MC-41807&type=commits

To fix this issue on your site, Magento 2.4.2, you just need to apply the changes in the commit https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6e6fff2a87221cd71f0f9e347a1cf35b3460d13f
Then run the following command to apply the changes:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Related topic [Magento 2: What is the purpose of "_replica" tables?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329204/magento-2-what-is-the-purpose-of-replica-tables)